# Defining static const integer members in class definition

Tags: c++, static, declaration, definition

My understanding is that C++ allows static const members to be defined inside a class so long as it's an integer type.

Why, then, does the following code give me a linker error?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    static const int N = 10;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << test::N << "\n";
    std::min(9, test::N);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `test::N'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the call to std::min, the code compiles and links just fine (even though test::N is also referenced on the previous line).

Any idea as to what's going on?

My compiler is gcc 4.4 on Linux.

Comment: Works fine on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This exact error is explained at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition

Comment: In the particular case of `char`, you can define it instead as `constexpr static const char &N = "n"[0];`. Note the `&`. I guess this works because literal strings are defined automatically. I'm kinda worried about this though - it might behave strangely in a header file among different translation units, as the string will probably be at multiple different addresses.

Comment: This question is a manifest of how poor the C++ answer to "do not use #defines for constants" still is.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann In this regard, I want to mention the use of inline for global variables since C++17 `inline const int N = 10`, which to my knowledge still has a storage somewhere defined by linker. Keyword inline could also be used in this case to provide static variable _definition_ inside the class definition test.

Comment: How do I use a static const int variable in another class?

Comment: It looks like a dummy GCC linker rule to me... no need to overcomplicate something that is parsed correctly just for the GCC linker honestly.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For over a decade now C++ provides the `constexpr` keyword that handles this nonsense and much more.  Declare your value as `static constexpr` and it won't need a definition.  The rest of this answer still applies to people consigned to hell permanently.

---

> My understanding is that C++ allows static const members to be defined inside a class so long as it's an integer type.

You are sort of correct.  You are allowed to initialize static const integrals in the class declaration but that is not a definition.

> Interestingly, if I comment out the call to std::min, the code compiles and links just fine (even though test::N is also referenced on the previous line).
>
> Any idea as to what's going on?

std::min takes its parameters by const reference.  If it took them by value you'd not have this problem but since you need a reference you also need a definition.

Here's chapter/verse:

> **9.4.2/4** - If a `static` data member is of `const` integral or `const` enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *constant-initializer* which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19).  In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions.  The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.

See Chu's answer for a possible workaround.

Comment: I see, that's interesting. In that case, what is the difference between providing the value at the point of declaration versus providing the value at the point of definition? Which one is recommended?

Comment: Well, I believe that you can get away without a definition so long as you never actually "use" the variable.  If you only use it as a part of a constant expression then the variable is never used.  Otherwise there doesn't seem to be a huge difference besides being able to see the value in the header - which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: The terse answer is static const x=1; is an rvalue but not an lvalue.  The value is available as a constant at compile time (you can dimension an array with it)   static const y; [no initializer] must be defined in a cpp file and may be used either as an rvalue or an lvalue.

Comment: It would be nice if they could extend/improve this. initialized-but-not-defined objects should, in my opinion, be treated the same as literals. For example, we are allowed to bind a literal `5` to a `const int&`. So why not treat the OP's `test::N` as the corresponding literal?

Comment: Interesting explanation, thanks! This means that in C++ static const int is still no replacement for integer #defines. enum is always only signed int, so one has to use enum classes for individual constants. It would be quite obvious to me to degenerate a constant declaration with constant and know values to a literal constant in which way this would compile without problems. C++ has a long way to go ...

Comment: Indeed, the problem with references is that we demand a storage for the object. Fun facts: 1) with optimizations turned on the call to `std::min(9, test::N)` gracefully compiles; then I thought putting parenthesis around `test::N` would make the expression rvalue but -- not that simple -- 2) the code `std::min(9, (test::N))` doesn't compile; then rvalue reference is still a _reference_, so 4) `std::min(9, reinterpret_cast<const int&&>(test::N))` or `std::min(9, std::move(test::N))` are no-go too; and finally 5) `std::min(9, test::N+0)` does the dirty trick. [Check out](http://cpp.sh/6zjcr)

Answer (score 60):

Bjarne Stroustrup's example [in his C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#in-class) suggests you are correct, and only need a definition if you take the address.

```
class AE {
    // ...
public:
    static const int c6 = 7;
    static const int c7 = 31;
};

const int AE::c7;   // definition

int f()
{
    const int* p1 = &AE::c6;    // error: c6 not an lvalue
    const int* p2 = &AE::c7;    // ok
    // ...
}
```

He says *"You can take the address of a static member if (and only if) it has an out-of-class definition"*.  Which suggests it would work otherwise.  Maybe your min function invokes addresses somehow behind the scenes.

Comment: `std::min` takes its parameters by reference, which is why a definition is required.

Comment: How would I write the definition if AE is a template class AE<class T> and c7 is not an int but T::size_type? I have the value initialized to "-1" in the header but clang says undefined value and I don't know how to write the definition.

Comment: @Fabian I am traveling and on a phone and a bit busy...but I would think that your comment sounds like it would be best written as a new question.  Write up a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the error you get, also maybe throw in what gcc says.  I bet people would tell you quickly what's what.

Comment: @HostileFork: When writing a MCVE, you sometimes figure the solution out yourself. For my case the answer is `template<class K, class V, class C>
const typename AE<K,V,C>::KeyContainer::size_type AE<K,V,C>::c7;` where KeyContainer is a typedef of std::vector<K>. One must list all template parameters and write typename because it's a dependent type. Maybe someone will find this comment useful. However, now I wonder how to export this in a DLL because the template class is of course in a header. Do I need to export c7???

Answer (score 26):

Another way to do this, for integer types anyway, is to define constants as enums in the class:

```
class test
{
public:
    enum { N = 10 };
};
```

Comment: And this would probably solve the problem.  When N is used as a parameter for min() it will cause a temporary to be created rather than try to refer to a supposedly existing variable.

Comment: This had the advantage that it can be made private.

Answer (score 14):

Not just int's.  But you can't define the value in the class declaration.  If you have:

```
class classname
{
    public:
       static int const N;
}
```

in the .h file then you must have:

```
int const classname::N = 10;
```

in the .cpp file.

Comment: I am aware that you can *declare* a variable of any type inside the class declaration. I said that I thought static integer constants could also be *defined* inside the class declaration. Is this not the case? If not, why is it that the compiler does not give an error at the line where I try to define it inside the class? Moreover, why does the std::cout line not cause a linker error, but the std::min line does?

Comment: No, can't define static members in the class declaration because the initialization emits code.  Unlike an inline function which also emits code, a static definition is globally unique.

Comment: @HighCommander4: You can supply an initializer for the `static const` integral member in the class definition. But that still *does not define* that member. See Noah Roberts answer for details.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way to work around the problem:

```
std::min(9, int(test::N));
```

(I think Crazy Eddie's answer correctly describes why the problem exists.)

Comment: or even `std::min(9, +test::N);`

Comment: Here's the big question though: is all this optimal? I don't know about you guys, but my big attraction to skipping the definition is that it should take up no memory and no overhead in using the const static.

Answer (score 8):

As of C++11 you can use:

`static constexpr int N = 10;`

This theoretically still requires you to define the constant in a .cpp file, but as long as you don't take the address of `N` it is very unlikely that any compiler implementation will produce an error ;).

Comment: And what if you need to pass the value as an argument of type 'const int&' like in the example? :-)

Comment: That works fine. You're not *instantiating* N that way, merely passing a const reference to a temporary. https://wandbox.org/permlink/JWeyXwrVRvsn9cBj

Comment: C++17 maybe, not C++14, and even not C++17 in earlier versions of gcc 6.3.0 and lower, it's not a standard thing. But thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I didn't try c++14 on wandbox. Oh well, that is the part where I said "This theoretically still requires you to define the constant". So, you are right that it is not 'standard'.

Answer (score 3):

> C++ allows static const members to be defined inside a class

Nope, 3.1 §2 says:

> **A declaration is a definition unless** it declares a function without specifying the function's body (8.4), it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a functionbody, **it declares a static data member in a class definition** (9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is an opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), or it is a typedef declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration (7.3.3), or a using-directive (7.3.4).