# Linker gives error "undefined symbol" for integral static const members used in certain contexts

Tags: c++, linker, initialization, standards, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ - defining static const integer members in class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025997/c-defining-static-const-integer-members-in-class-definition)

Note: There are several extant questions re similar issues, but I have reviewed many of them and cannot find an answer that explains this behavior:

Say I have code such as the following (in a **header** file)

```
class Foo {
    static const int TEST = 33;

    public:
    void willItWork(void) {
        printf("%d", std::max(TEST, 75));  // embedded platform, no streams
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Foo tester;
    tester.willItWork();
}
```

This will compile, but it will not link. I get the linker error

> Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol Foo::TEST (referred from foo.o).

It only seems like passing the value to outside functions causes problems. Using `TEST` in ordinary expressions or functions within the class works fine. If I instead write `willItWork()` as

```
void willItWork(void) {
    int diff = TEST - 23;
    printf("%d", diff);
}
```

there is no error.

I found another question that referenced the C++ standard regarding this (Section 9.4.2):

> If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a const-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression.

Since what I have done seems to be "within the rules," can anyone think of any possible explanation for this odd behavior?

I tried similar code on ideone and had no issue (however, I can not mimic the exact structure, i.e. with header files, there). Does this mean the linker I am using doesn't quite conform to the standard here?

Any insight is greatly appreciated. I can always provide more information, too.

Comment: In this case passing the variable by value also will keep it from linking, as long as the function it is passed to is external (e.g. in a different class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the compiler feels it needs the address of the `static` member variable, e.g., when binding the variable to a reference at some point, it will create a corresponding undefined symbol and you will have to define the member:

```
int const foo::TEST;
```

(in one translation unit). If the compiler only ever accesses a the value you can get away with not defining the object. Unless you need the type to be an `int`, you can use an `enum` instead and avoid the need for defining the member:

```
enum { TEST = 33 };
```

The term in the standard to look for is *odr-used* if I recall correctly.

Comment: +1, the standard deals with this in *3.2 One Definition Rule* the the term is *odr-used* in C++11 (plain *used* in C++03).

Answer (score 3):

`std::max` takes its arguments by reference, not by value. Binding a reference to your static const requires an actual object, not just the value.

Comment: I forget -- does the definition need the initializer, too?

Comment: If the variable is already initialized at its declaration, it cannot be initialized at its definition.

Comment: If I pass the value to an external function of my own that takes arguments by value, it still generates the error.

Comment: @Robᵩ Okay, I think I figured it out...I was accessing my external function through a reference to the class that contained said function. Would that cause this problem in the same way?

Comment: And just out of curiosity, if `TEST` is essentially equivalent to a literal, does std::max() (and the rest of the library) then handle "actual" literals in some clever way that allows them to be passed by reference?