# unresolved external symbol when static variable is defined inside the class declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static

I am going to get right to the point:

```
//ComponentHolder.h

template<class Holder, uint ID>
class TemplateComponentHolder : public ComponentHolderInterface {
protected:
    std::vector<ComponentType*> mComponents;


public:
   TemplateComponentHolder() : ComponentHolderInterface(ID) {}

   static const uint getStaticID() { return ID; }
};

class ConcereteComponentHolder1 : public TemplateClassHolder<ComponentType, 1000> {
public:
    inline void print() { std::cout << "test"; }
};

//World.h
class World {
private:
   std::map<uint, ComponentHolderInterface*> mHolders;
public:
   template<class Holder> Holder * getHolder() {
       auto i = mHolders.find(Holder::getStaticID());
       if(i != mHolders.end())
          return static_cast<Holder*>((*i));
       return NULL;
   }

   /* ... */
};

//Main code
int main() {
  World * world = new World;
  world->addHolder(new ConcerteComponentHolder1);

  world->getHolder<ConcreteComponentHolder1>()->print();
}
```

I get unresolved external symbol error. Says cannot resolve "ConcereteComponentHolder1::ID". If I change the static variable to non const and add it to a source file:

```
//ComponentHolder.cpp
uint ConcreteComponentHolder1::ID = 1000;
```

There is no problem. It makes sense why the latter one must be defined explicitly. But when I am using `const`, I have to define it in the header. Getting a linker error when using const just doesn't make sense. Is it because of the template function being generated in the header? Or is it something else?

Comment: "When I am using `const`, I have to define it in the header". Why?

Comment: I just realized that I can use const in the definition. I just wish there was an easier way to approach this problem. Like using a static `getId()`, then I won't need to define it every time.

Comment: If you're really using C++11 it is possible: `constexpr uint getId() { return 1; }`

Comment: Not only did getting right to the point not really get right to the point, after you edited your code the question made little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing a variable declaration together with an initialiser in the class declaration dies not actually constitute a definition. You can get away without the definition as long as you only ever take it's value and never try to use it as a reference.

'find' takes a reference to the value as an argument. This means you need an actual variable defined somewhere to take a reference to it.

You might also like to read this SO question: [Defining static const integer members in class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025997/c-defining-static-const-integer-members-in-class-definition)

Comment: one question. Instead of using ID as a variable I have created a getStaticID() static function and each subclass defines it all. Please check my edited new code. the getStaticId works as expected but I want to know if its just my compiler linking it correctly or is it a valid code? Can derived class access the static function of a parent class?

Comment: Because you are using a template function which in which the specific class is parameterized, you are accessing the static method of the derived class, not the parent. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Btw probably best not to edit the question like that. The question and the answer now do not make sense to anyone else searching for this kind of problem.