# Initialization of static member variable

Tags: c++, static

Why does class support the initialization of the static variable inside the
class with const keyword and without const keyword why does not allow to
initialize the static variable inside the class

```
class test  
{  
public:  
 int x;  

 static int y = 2; // It will throw an error  
 static const int z = 3; // It will not throw an error, why?  
};  

int main()  
{  
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Use dot and commas, question is hard to understand

Comment: It is to ease linker and the ODR. where would be the definition of `test::y` ?

Comment: You can't declare non-const in definition, only define it. And then you must declare it outside class in cpp file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining static const integer members in class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025997/defining-static-const-integer-members-in-class-definition)

Comment: "The static keyword is only used with the declaration of a static member, inside the class definition, but not with the definition of that static member": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: Because they are declarations, not definitions. `static const int` and other integral types are special cases

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/185848/868044

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)