# Linker error when using static const members in templates (e.g. std::min)

Tags: c++

Today I encountered a some compiler behaviour which seemed rather strange to me. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct test {
    static const int x = 1;
    static const int y = 2;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::min(test::x, test::y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (with either g++ 5.4, 6.3 or clang++ 4.0), the linker complains that it can not resolve the two symbols test::x and test::y.

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -o test  
/tmp/test-3cd074.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `test::x'
test.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `test::y'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, when explicitly (and redundantly) casting the static members to their original type, the compilation succeeds:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::min(static_cast<const int>(test::x), static_cast<const int>(test::y)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This leads to the expected result:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp  -o test && ./test  
1
```

Just outputting the variables via std::cout works without a cast, so does initializing another variable with the values:

```
std::cout << test::x << std::endl; // Works!
int z = test::y; // Works as well!
```

Now my question is: Why can't the linker resolve the symbols when the static members are not being casted? Why is accessing the members not a problem when accessing them outside of a template?

Comment: May be a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025997/1896169

Comment: `test::x` etc. are not symbols.

Comment: Thanks Justin, the linked question helps to clear things up. However, I'm still wondering why casting the variables solves the problem as well. Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: @andreas-hofmann Remember to tag someone with @ if you want them to see it. From the accepted answer, the reason why it works is because `static const int x = 1;` isn't a definition of `x`, it's a "constant-initializer". Basically, you could write `int myInt = test::x` and it would work just fine, because the compiler says, "Oh, I can just replace `test::x` with `1`". However, you can't take a reference to it, which is why passing it to `std::min` fails. When you cast it, you never take a reference to `test::x`. It forces `std::min`'s argument to bind to the temporary rather than to `test::x`.

Comment: Thanks again @Justin. Temporary gave me the right idea.